# How do you place a HTML table inside a PHP coding

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

I have been trying to insert a html table into the PHP code. So that the echo-ed data (e.g., air reading) can be displayed in a table. Please help.

```
    <?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "100000000000000000";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
?>


<?php

    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "sensors_hub";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT air_reading, co2_reading, gas_reading, humid_reading, temp_reading FROM sensor_001 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> Air Reading: ". $row["air_reading"]. "  Carbon Dioxide Reading: ". $row["co2_reading"]." Gas Reading: ". $row["gas_reading"]. " Humidity Reading: ". $row["humid_reading"]. " Temp Reading: ". $row["temp_reading"]. "<br>";

     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: html is text. you output it like you would output any OTHER text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Start your table above the `while()` loop
- Add a table row in the `while()` loop
- End the table after the `while()` loop

```
echo "<table>
        <tr>
          <th>Air Reading</th>
          <th>Carbon Dioxide Reading</th>
          <th>Gas Reading</th>
          <th>Humidity Reading</th>
          <th>Temp Reading</th>
        </tr>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr>
                <td>". $row["air_reading"]. "</td>
                <td>". $row["co2_reading"]."</td>
                <td> ". $row["gas_reading"]. "</td>
                <td>". $row["humid_reading"]. "</td>
                <td>". $row["temp_reading"]. "</td>
               </tr>";
     }
} else {
     echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>0 results</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>Air Reading:</td>";
  echo "<td>Carbon Dioxide Reading:</td>";
  echo "<td>Gas Reading:</td>";
  echo "<td>Humidity Reading:</td>";
  echo "<td>Temp Reading:</td>";
echo "</tr>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td> ". $row["air_reading"]. "</td>";
     echo "<td> ". $row["co2_reading"]. "</td>";
     echo "<td> ". $row["gas_reading"]. "</td>";
     echo "<td> ". $row["humid_reading"]. "</td>";
     echo "<td> ". $row["temp_reading"]. "</td>";
     }
  echo "</tr>";
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}

echo "</table>";
```

This is probalby the most writing-effort, but the easiest to understand.

If you want to do it smarter, to it like this:

```
?><table>
  <tr>
  <td>Air Reading:</td>
   <td>Carbon Dioxide Reading:</td>
   <td>Gas Reading:</td>
   <td>Humidity Reading:</td>
   <td>Temp Reading:</td>
 </tr> 
 <?
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       ?>
         <tr> 
           <td><?=$row["air_reading"]?></td> 
           <td><?=$row["co2_reading"]?></td> 
           <td><?=$row["gas_reading"]?></td> 
           <td><?=$row["humid_reading"]?></td> 
           <td><?=$row["temp_reading"]?></td> 

         </tr> 
       <?
     }
 } else {
   ?>0 results<?
 }
?>

 </table>
```

Comment: Do it smarter! 
You should remove that first snippet - don't teach people how to write crummy code - bonus points if you mention doing it with 'include'

Comment: In both of those examples, you're never actually creating new `<tr>`s for each row.

Comment: @nkorth oh yeah, you right. I botched that. give me a min to fix it.

Comment: @rm-vanda I agree that he should learn the second way straight up. But I think the second one is way harder to understand if you haven't seen the first way first.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    ?>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Air Reading<th>
        <th>Carbon Dioxide Reading<th>
        <th>Gas Reading<th>
        <th>Humidity Reading<th>
        <th>Temp Reading<th>
    </tr>
    <?PHP while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php= $row["air_reading"] ?></td>
        <td><?php= $row["co2_reading"] ?></td>
        <td><?php= $row["gas_reading"] ?></td>
        <td><?php= $row["humid_reading"] ?></td>
        <td><?php= $row["temp_reading"] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?PHP } ?>
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the table above the while loop, and end it after it finishes.My answer is similar to hd's, but I find this way is more useful:

```
$table = "<table>";
$table .= "<tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>";

$i = 0;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $table .= "<tr><td>Col 1</td></tr>";
     }

} 

$table .= "</table>";

echo $table;
```

The reason I prefer this way is that it makes your HTML code easier to read, as you can now echo the table within the HTML code, rather than doing the whole PHP script in the middle of HTML.